# Alphabetical sort of list in Google Keep

Tags: google-keep

I'm using Google Keep to make my grocery list and share it with my family. The problem I've found is that when I have many items checked and i want to uncheck one of them (e.g., "ice"), it's very difficult to find it. There's no suggestion when I'm creating a new item in my list, either. So I can create "Ice" 2 times and my list is growing unnecessarily.

Is there any feature to order checked items? Any other suggestion?

Comment: For everyone finding this question: Please submit feedback to google as I just did. Maybe that'll increase the chance of them implementing sorting. Ref https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/Lnhmp0MK70A

Answer (score 10):

Here's how, but this only works for new lists -- it won't work nicely if you already have some items checked:

- Open your list in Keep (web)
- Go to overflow menu (3 vertical dots) and choose "Hide Checkboxes" -- your list is now converted into text
- Copy text to any app that supports sorting (e.g. any spreadsheet app; some text editors support that too)
- Sort the text
- Copy it back into the note, overwriting original text
- Go to overflow menu, pick "Show Checkboxes"

Note, if you already have some items checked, you still have an easy option to delete them all (Keep will ask you about it when you chose "Hide Checkboxes").

Comment: Note that the `Hide Checkboxes` command is lossy if you use nested items as they all get flattened to top level.

Comment: Okay, now I feel silly for not thinking of this on my own.  Great suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no function in Keep that I can see.  The only option I can think of is:

- Use the Copy to Google Doc option from the More menu at the bottom of
  the list
- Open the Google Doc
- Copy the items from the list
- Make a new Google Spreadsheet,
- Paste the copied items
- Use the Sort function (Data > Sort)
- Copy the results
- Go back to Keep and make a new list
- Paste (puts the results, one per line into the list).
- Delete the old list.
- Re-set up Sharing or the new list.

Yes, that's horrible.    It might be ok for a once off (if you have an enormous list - sort it like that once, mantain it manually after that).   Let's hope they add a sort function to Keep soon.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar method to one of these other [answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82564/119674) - converting to text with "Hide checkboxes" and the reverse later.

I usually remove duplicates by using a site like [Text Fixer](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/alphabetize-text-words.php).

Comment: Please note that "above" has no context in answers. Since answers can be sorted in several ways, your answer could very well be "above" the ones to which you are referring. To refer to another answer, it's best to link to it.

Comment: Good point, I will change to links @AlE.