# How can I sort notes by most recently edited?

Tags: google-keep

I'm using Google Keep but it's not like any other note apps I've used in the past.

I make edits to notes and then I can't find them because the sort order doesn't change.

Is there a way for Google Keep to sort the most recently edited notes to the top?

Answer (score 0):

It's crystal clear that Google Keep is distinct from other note-taking apps. That is how Google does things. Sometimes, they nail it, like with Google (Google Search), their signature product, Gmail and others, and sometimes not.

If you want to keep a note on the top, **pin it**.

Use labels to organize your notes. Bear in mind that Google Keeps is integrated with Gmail, Calendar, Drive and Google Editors. I.E. a note can be linked to a Gmail message.

The following image shows the Google Keeps settings:

[image: Google Keep Settings]

Related

- [Alphabetical sort of list in Google Keep](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82518/88163)
- [Is it possible to pin a note above all other in Keep?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99282/88163)
- [Sort Google Keep "Titles" in alphabetical order](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136173/88163)